# Increase WKInterfaceLabel font size if space is available

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacelabel, watchos-3

I have a screen in my watch app that just contains 1 WKInterfaceLabel, set to 0 lines. It's width and height are set to "Size to Fit Content".

I want all the text to fit on one screen, without any scrolling.

At runtime, I need to be able to reduce the font size for long strings, so everything will fit without needing to scroll. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try to set super-big font size and small min scale in Interface Builder? So by default text will be longer than screen and will be downscaled until it will suit label's size